# Rails 4.2.6 sprockets not working in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sprockets, rails-sprockets

I'm not sure why this is happening but it's driving me nuts. I'm trying to update rails from `4.1.1` to the latest stable version `4.2.6`. Up updating nothing strange happend, the assets are now listed in assets.rb.

**I found out that it brakes on updating the `sprockets` gem to `3.5.2`, so forced it back to `2.11.0`, but this is not a fix.**

However in development mode with `config.assets.debug = true` the header file has no stylesheet linked, why?!

And if I try to `rake assets:precompile` the created files are empty. Do I forgot something?

[image: header]

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

  # Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all assets,
  # yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Adds additional error checking when serving assets at runtime.
  # Checks for improperly declared sprockets dependencies.
  # Raises helpful error messages.
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
end
```

And the layout;

```
!!! 5
%html
  %head
    %meta{content: "IE=edge", "http-equiv" => "X-UA-Compatible"}
    %meta{content: "width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no", name: "viewport"}

    = stylesheet_link_tag 'default', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
    = javascript_include_tag 'default', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
```

`Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( default.css )` in assets.rb

Comment: Does it make a difference if you set the version of `sprockets-rails` in your Gemfile to `2.3.3`?

Comment: It doesn't make a difference, I don't get why the `= stylesheet_link_tag` is not creating html, if I put the `config.assets.debug = false` I renders the html but the digests are empty.

I also tried different ruby versions (`2.1.3`, `2.3.0`) doesn't change a thing. I guess I shouldn't have updated it all at once. @sean

Comment: @SeanHuber you were very close. It was `sprockets` gem, I forced it back to version `2.11.0` which in turns requires `2.3.3` from `sprockets-rails`. Now off course i still want to fix it